# How to deploy a socket.io from nodejs on Tomcat

Tags: node.js, sockets, tomcat, deployment, socket.io

Here's the thing, I have a folder, using Nodejs and socket.io(it's a chat) and I also have a server running Tomcat 8. I have worked with .war and .ear files before in Tomcat, but I'm new in this nodejs deployment thing.
Do you guys have like a tutorial or can you explain me how can I like package my app and then deploy it, or upload the folder, I don't know, something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need tomcat to run  your node.js application. Just be sure node is installed on your server and the port you are using is allowed on your server's firewall and you are good to go. (Don't forget to install your npm packages through your packages.json of course)

Usually a node.js app is run like below;

```
node server.js
```

And that's all. If you'd like to keep it alive or restart in any case of issue you can use forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

If you want to load balance with reverse proxy or if you want to configure ssl etc. you can use nginx or haproxy etc.

If you want to automate your deployment you can create a hook to your git source (github, bitbucket etc.) and write down a script to stop / start your node processes, fetch modified files, install npm packages etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, really helped me out. What I did was install Node as you said, open ports 3000 and 3001(they were 2 apps using same ports), go to the server terminal via SSH, and go node "appname.js" and that was it! 
Both apps up and running.